# WinAppDeployCmd doesn't show devices

Tags: windows-phone, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I tried to deploy my Windows phone 10 package to device.

1. I created package from VS2015 (.appx)
2. Switched on dev mode on mobile device (with win phone 10)
3. Plugged mobile device to PC with USB
4. Ran command WinAppDeployCmd devices 10

And still WinAppDeployCmd is unable to find any device.

How should I setup WinAppDeployCmd to make it able to find my mobile device?

Thank you.

Comment: Does your PC start the Windows Phone Companion app when plugging the phone in?

Comment: Yes, it starts Phone Companion

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

1. [PC]create package in VS2015 (.appx)
2. [Mobile]Go to Settings=>Update and Security=>For developers=>switch on Developer mode
3. [Mobile]Switch on Wi-Fi and connect to network (the same network as PC)
4. [Mobile]Go to Settings=>Network & wireless=>Wi-Fi=>press network name you connected to=>find IP address
5. [Mobile]Go to Settings=>Update and Security=>For developers=>switch on Device discovery=>press Pair=>remember code
6. [PC]run command WinAppDeployCmd install -file "path to .appx file" -ip [IP address from 4th step] -pin [code from 5th step]

It helps deploy package to device